# How do I log tqdm console output to a file in Python?

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm working on a task that requires me to log the console output of tqdm to a file.

Using the below snippet tqdm shows progress bars in the console.

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

for x in tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(.5)
```

I used the `file` parameter to log the output to a file like this:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

for x in tqdm(range(10), file = open('/tmp/temp_log.log', 'w')):
    time.sleep(.5)
```

and I'm able to achieve my expected output. However when I use the `file` param, `tqdm` does not print any progress bars to the console.

How do can I print the progress bars to the console while logging the output to a file simultaneously?

I've tried using the `tqdm-logger` module but it only logs the final progress bar as opposed to logging all the bars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of brain storming I found a smart way to tackle this issue:

*To display the `tqdm` console output, wrap the existing tqdm object (the logger) with another `tqdm` object like this:*

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

for x in tqdm(

tqdm(range(10), file = open('/tmp/temp_log.log', 'w')),

 desc = 'TQDM Console'):

    time.sleep(.5)
```

The snippet now logs and outputs identical bars and timings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the bar manually.

```
pbar = tqdm(total = 10)
for x in tqdm(range(10), file = open('/tmp/temp_log.log', 'w')):
    pbar.update(1)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

That code creates a log file and shows the bar. It's like using a second bar.

Comment: Will the details like elapsed time, iteration time displayed usually on tqdm  be identical on both outputs?

Comment: Good question, I had the same problem in a project and solved it like that. Never figured out differences between the console output and the log files.

Comment: Just gave your answer a go and it looks like the timings aren't the same, but looks like this might be an easy workaround for someone who just wants a simple progress bar with incremental updates